# Carousel slider to be displayed

Tags: slider

I want the carousel slider with the 3rd image to be half displayed and on click the right side navigation icon the 3rd image need to be displayed first and rest 2 images need to be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is Lemmon carousal

Check this out. Will be very useful
http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php